# need help on this SQL lab Unit 1

Tags: sql

thia is my homework. I am not how to code it

The Horse table has the following columns:

| Column | Datatype | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | integer | primary key |
| RegisteredName | variable-length string |  |
| Breed | variable-length string |  |
| Height | decimal number |  |
| BirthDate | date |  |

Write a SELECT statement to select the registered name, height, and birth date for only horses that have a height between 15.0 and 16.0 (inclusive) or have a birth date on or after January 1, 2020.

NOTE: Starter code has been provided. Simply change the blanks ("_") to the appropriate entity/value.

490374.2803420.qx3zqy7
LAB ACTIVITY
12.1.1: Unit 5 Lab 1
0 / 10
Main.sql
Load default template...
OR ___________ >= '2020-01-01'

Develop mode

Submit mode
Explore the database and run your program as often as you'd like, before submitting for grading. Click Run program and observe the program's output in the second box.

Run program
Main.sql
(Your program)
Output (shown below)
Program errors displayed here
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'test.2020___________' doesn't existease and

Well, I did to think of how it is supposed to go, but no luck.

Comment: Please take the tour and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) like you were asked to, and also [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), then edit your question accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    RegisteredName,
    Height,
    BirthDate
from Horses
where Height between 15 and 16
or Birthdate >= '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, could you perhaps explain why?